# Excel Macro To Multiply Lines Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I would need some help with the following:

I have a list of unique products in column A (product 1, product 2 etc.).
In column B next to every product I have the current stock (14, 6 etc.) of every product.

Can somebody help me out with a macro that would turn this list into a list that would consist of 14 lines of product 1 and 6 lines of product 2 (in column A)?

Many thanks for your help in advance

Stephan

Comment: So if stock for "product 1" is 14, then you wish to see "product 1" appear 14 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a macro that generate x times "Product 1" and y times "Product 2" on column A (x=16 and y=4 on your case), i built [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUSCX.png):

Code:

```
Private Sub Execute_btn_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Last_Row As Long

For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value
    Cells(i, 1).Value = "Product 1"
Next i

Last_Row = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To TextBox2.Value
    Cells(Last_Row + j, 1) = "Product 2"
Next j

Unload Me
End Sub
```